# I want to concatenate two arrays in java such that below condition is satisfied

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
  String[] a = {1, 2, 3};
  String[] b = {4, 5, 6};
```

And result should be like below:

```
  String[]c = {"1":"4","2":"5", "3":"6"}
```

i.e. Simply the concatenation of a[i] and b[i] to make one field in c[i]

```
c[0] = "a[0]":"b[0]"
     =  "1":"4"
c[1] = "a[1]":"b[1]"
     =  "2":"5" ........... and so on.
```

later on, i would use array c[] in an ArrayList to print the values:

```
    for (int j=0;j<c.length,j++)
    {           
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("c[i]");
    }
```

I am interested in the concatenation of a and b in c in the format as described above.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you maybe want a `Map<Integer, Integer>`?

Comment: what is **:** in resultant array

Comment: `int[]c = {"1"` is not valid. `"1"` is a String which cannot be stored in an `int`.

Comment: An `int[]` array `c` cannot contain Strings, and please explain what you mean by the colon in this array - that's not Java array syntax.

Comment: Because, in Java, you cannot resize an array, you will have to create a new array of appropriate length (`a.length + b.length`) first. Then copy each entry from the source arrays into the new array at its respective position. Hint: `b[i]` goes to the position immediately after `a[i]`.

Comment: @Prashant Varun You want output to be printed as `"1":"4","2":"5", "3":"6"` or entire new `int` array?

Comment: where is your effort ?

Comment: Basically my requirement is, i have two map the fields on same index ( or assign 1=4,2=5) between these two arrays ( a & b ) mentioned above. 

And result should come in the form of:

String[] ResultArray = {"1":"4","2":"5", "3":"6"}

Is it possible if above can be formed by joining the elements and include extra characters like ["",:], such that it is only printed like {"1":"4","2":"5", "3":"6"}

Hence i want to show that 1=4, 2 = 5, but the result representation is like below only:

{"1":"4","2":"5", "3":"6"}.


THanks.

Comment: @PrashantVarun do you want to store the array or just print it??

Comment: {"CreationTime":"2017-11-03T00:00:20Z","MdIfName":"HexBinary","ServiceId":"2017-11-03T00:00:20.403"}....

This is sample output, where A:B, A & B belongs to different Arrays

Comment: @Lino: Store as well.

Comment: @QBrute:Yes, it is more like a mapping of 1=4,2=5 and result in another csv file like:

String Result;

cat Result : ( A csv file of 2 records here )
{"1":"4","2":"5", "3":"6"}
{"1":"4","2":"5", "3":"6"}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the array has the same size for a and b and since you didn`t specify the dict i used strings:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++)
    map.put(a[i], b[i]);
```

Comment: the if can be removed, the OP never mentioned anything about a condition

Comment: Sorry i got confused by the title, will edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want an array containing all the elements from the arrays `a` and `b`, which the following code provides:

```
final int[] c = new int[a.length + b.length];
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
     c[i] = a[i];
     c[i+1] = b[i];
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
```

prints:

```
 [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

Comment: Well to be very specific:

Array A contains: my headers. ( Name, Age )
Array B will contains there values:
like
(John,17)
(Alex,21)

I want to map my headers from A with these values in B, such that it will create a string per record:

{"Name":"John","Age":"17"}
{"Name":"Alex","Age":"21"}
So on for further records as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
String a[] ={"Name", "Age"};
    String b [][] ={{"J","12"},{"P","23"}};
    System.out.print(a.length + b.length);
    String res[][] = new String[2][4];

        for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<b[j].length;k++){

                if(k==0){
                    res[j][k] = a[k];
                    res[j][k+1] =  b[j][k];
                }else{
                    res[j][k+1] = a[k];
                    res[j][k+2] =  b[j][k];
                }


                }
            }


        for(int j=0;j<res.length;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<res[j].length;k++){
                System.out.print(" \"" +res[j][k] +"\"");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: This is same as above answer

Comment: @priyanka: Well to be very specific:

Array A contains: my headers. ( Name, Age )
Array B will contains there values:
like
(John,17)
(Alex,21)

I want to map my headers from A with these values in B, such that it will create a string per record:

{"Name":"John","Age":"17"}
{"Name":"Alex","Age":"21"}
So on for further records as well.